# SailsJS MongoDB Database connection error

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

I am new for SailsJS. I am trying to create database connection with mongo but it shows error like this

```
A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: Error: Consistency violation: A model (`sleep`) references a datastore which cannot be found (`mongo`).
If this model definition has an explicit `connection` property, check that it is spelled correctly.
If not, check your default `connection` (usually located in `config/models.js`).
Finally, check that this connection (`mongo`) is valid as per http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-connections.
```

Comment: You'll need to post a small amount of code that can help people reproduce this problem, or at least identify the flaw.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is connecting to an invalid connection 'mongo'.

Check the connection either in you model 'Sleep' or in config/models.js